# Onsen force reload on ons-tab with attribute persistent

Tags: onsen-ui

Is there a way to force reload/refresh content of ons-tab with persistent attribute?

My problem is all the ng-show or ng-hide inside the tabs are not working when switching switching tabs.

This is my structure:

**tab 1: login.html**

**tab 2: home.html** *w/ login button when user is not logged in , video list if logged in*

**tab 3. account.html**

Obviously, I want to hide the login button and show the video list in the home tab after logging in, but not working due to the persistent attribute.

Comment: Perhaps you need to do `$scope.$apply()` after login to update Angular view? In any case, `myTabbar.loadPage(url)` loads a new page in the current tab, so you can use it to refresh.